# Problem in filling SelectOneMenu with data

Tags: jsf, icefaces

in my ApplicationBean1.java class I have an Option[] attribute years and a filling method:

```
public void buildYearOptions(){
    int initialYear = 1900;
    int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int i = 0;
    for (int y = initialYear; y< currentYear; y++){
        Option op = new Option(y, Integer.toString(y));
        years[i] = op;
        i++;   
    }     
 }
```

And this is my jsp page using icefaces:

```
<ice:selectOneMenu id="selectOneYearMenu" partialSubmit="true"
    style="height: 24px; left: 238px; top: 94px; position: absolute; width: 72px;visibility: visible;"
    visible="true">
    <f:selectItems id="selectOneMenuYearItems" value="#{ApplicationBean1.years}"/>
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

My problem is that the years from 1900 to currentyear(2010) are not showing up in the dropDownList (selectOneMenu).

Aan someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do IceFaces, so it might do things differently I am not aware of, but you normally feed the `f:selectItems` with a [`SelectItem[]`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html), [`List<SelectItem>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or a [`Map<Object, Object>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), not with an `Option[]` or whatever type it is.

This should work:

```
private List<SelectItem> years; // +getter.

public void buildYearOptions() {
    final int initialYear = 1900;
    final int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    for (int year = initialYear; year < currentYear; year++) {
        years.add(new SelectItem(year, String.valueOf(year)));
    }     
}
```

If it still doesn't give anything, then you're likely calling `buildYearOptions()` at the wrong moment or probably not calling it at all.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer it really helped.  Apparently in Icefaces, you cannot use the interface List , it only worked greatly when my field was with type ArrayList<SelectItem>:

private ArrayList<SelectItem> years;